# "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'a' not found" in function

Tags: r, function, survey

I have code in R I want to run for many variables to get descriptive statistics, so I'd like to create a function to make my code cleaner.

The code I first run for `variable` without trying with a function works well:

```
variable1 <- prop.table(svytable(~variable, ebase2mref))
variable2 <- as.data.frame(table(base$variable))
write.table(variable1 , file = "table.csv", sep = ",", append = TRUE)
write.table(variable2 , file = "table.csv", sep = ",", append = TRUE)
```

but when I try to run

```
e2m_desc <- function(a) {
  a1 <- prop.table(svytable(~a, ebase2mref))
  a2 <- as.data.frame(table(base$a))
  write.table(a1 , file = "table.csv", sep = ",", append = TRUE)
  write.table(a2 , file = "table.csv", sep = ",", append = TRUE)
}

e2m_desc(variable)
```

I get error "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'a' not found".

Code run beforehand for survey weights:

```
ebase2mrefdep <- base %>%
  drop_na(M02E_PONDREFC2)
ebase2mref <- svydesign(ids = ~1, data = ebase2mrefdep, weights = ~ ebase2mrefdep$M02E_PONDREFC2)
```

I've tried replacing `a` with some other name, tried with other variables. I also tried running the function with one line at a time, to try and isolate a problem with one of the lines, which gave the following:

```
e2m_desc <- function(a) {
  a1 <- prop.table(svytable(~a, ebase2mref))
}

e2m_desc(variable)
```

&

```
e2m_desc <- function(a) {
  a1 <- prop.table(svytable(~a, ebase2mref))
  write.table(a1 , file = "table.csv", sep = ",", append = TRUE)
}

e2m_desc(variable)
```

: gave error "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'a' not found"

```
e2m_desc <- function(a) {
  a2 <- as.data.frame(table(base$a))
  write.table(a2 , file = "table.csv", sep = ",", append = TRUE)
}

e2m_desc(variable)
```

: while this worked

Hope this is clear enough!

Thanks!

Comment: Please share more details, like the programming language you use and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your comment, first time here! Hope my edit helps

Comment: if you already solved your own question, please post an answer and accept it :))

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that your last one worked: `base$a` should return `NULL` unless there's a column called `a`.

Anyway, your problem is that you want to use `a` in a way that's not really natural in R. You want to extract the name of the actual argument (`variable`) without evaluating it, and then substitute it into two different expressions. That is, you're looking for a macro rather than a function.

It would be *easier* if you supplied some quoted form of the variable name as the argument: `"a"` or `~a`

```
f1<-function(string_a){
   formula<-make.formula(string_a)
   variable1 <- prop.table(svytable(formula, ebase2mref))
   variable2 <- as.data.frame(table(base[[string_a]]))
}
```

or

```
f1<-function(tilde_a){
   variable1 <- prop.table(svytable(tilde_a, ebase2mref))
   string_a<-tilde_a[[2]]
   variable2 <- as.data.frame(table(base[[string_a]]))
}
```

You can, however, do what you want to do with `bquote`

```
f1<-function(a){
   a <- substitute(a)
   variable1 <- eval(bquote(prop.table(svytable(~.(a), ebase2mref))
   variable2 <- eval(bquote(with(base, as.data.frame(table(.(a))))))
}
```

The switch from `base$a` to `with(base, a)` is because the `$` selector is sufficiently special that even `bquote` can't substitute into it.